# Frequency of appearing of audits in review queues - WHEN do they appear?

Tags: discussion, review, review-audit

As the subject seems to be about something nework-wide, I've asked [the same question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369123/315254) on the main meta site.

---

Today, I've made more than forty reviews in different queues on the main site. Strangely, more than ten of them (more than 25%) have been audits, which is something that hasn't happened to me before. More strangely, in the "Late answers" queue, I got two audits, one usual task after them and one more audit after that (which I think has never happened to me before; the "Late answers" cases have always been rare, audit or usual). It made me think about the algorithm responsible for choosing when to show an audit. I tried to make some guesses, but I think I ended up having more questions than good guesses. I ask some of them here, along with my guesses in the form of "is it because ..." questions, so that I make clear what I mean when I ask "how often" audits appear. I suppose they can be answered all at once by someone who knows about the algorithm.

- How often do audits appear?
- Today was the first day that the queues "First answers" and "First questions" were active. Is there something related to that?
- Is the number of audits appearing in a day related to the number of reviews done by the user that day? Is it related to the number of reviews done by all users that day?
- Is the type of reviews done by the user related to the type of audits appearing? (I suppose not; as I got two audits in the "Late answers" queue, where I hadn't done any reviews in a very long time.)
- Is the choice of the user in the previous reviews (for example to reopen a post or leave it closed) and its similarity with the choice of other reviewers a factor? What about failing or succeeding in the previous audits?
- Is the algorithm different (or with different weightings of parameters) for different communities, or is it the same for all the Overflow and Stack Exchange sites?
- Is the fact that I haven't ever got an audit on Meta because any of the above factors (or any other factor that affects the frequency of appearing of audits) is very low there, or is it because audits are only designed to appear on the main site?

---

After a [comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34039/frequency-of-appearing-of-audits-in-review-queues-when-do-they-appear?noredirect=1#comment156807_34039) by [postmortes](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/65078/postmortes), I've been thinking about this one, too:

- Is the number of audits one encounters related to the number of audits the algorithm can generate at that time, due to the number of post qualified for it? (See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168372/315254) for the criteria.)

Comment: Insight into the algorithm used can be found here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168366/failed-a-reopen-question-audit-sure-looks-like-not-a-real-question-to-me/168372#168372 -- as far as I know, it's the same across all stackexchanges.

Comment: First questions and first answers should be new - here is the announcement on [meta.se]: [Review queue workflows - Final release](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369013).

Comment: @postmortes Are you suggesting that the more there is audits to create (as is described how, in the link you shared) the more they will appear for any user?

Comment: @MohsenShahriari I'm suggesting nothing; I've provided a link on the main meta site regarding how the algorithm for review queues work.

Comment: @postmortes Thanks for clearing that up. Do you think the main meta site is the right place for asking this question? (I've searched there, and found nothing about "when" audits appear.)

Comment: @MohsenShahriari your question is certainly general enough to be answerable on the main meta, and I suspect you're more likely to get a good answer there.  With the recent changes to the review queues people (and devs) are currently paying attention to these kinds of questions.